# R: Graph a 2-D function?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function x^2+y^2=1, how can I graph this function in R?

I have tried:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SAID.png)

but it doesn't work and says:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApA6P.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To plot a circle:

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1)) 
theta <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 200) 
lines(x = cos(theta), y = sin(theta))
```

[image]

### Plot the unit circle with the origin and aspect ratio = 1

```
plot(0, 0, asp = 1, xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1))
lines(x = cos(theta), y = sin(theta), col = "red")
```

[image]

### Plotting a surface

We'll use a different function for this.

[image]

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  cos(x) + sin(y)
}

xvec <- yvec <- seq(-pi, pi, length = 100)
dat <- expand.grid(x = xvec, y = yvec)
zmat <- matrix(f(dat$x, dat$y), ncol = 100)

# use persp
persp(xvec, yvec, zmat)
```

[image]

```
# view from a different angle
persp(xvec, yvec, zmat, theta = 45)
```

[image]

#### Using ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
dat$z <- f(dat$x, dat$y)

ggplot(dat) + 
  aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient2()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x <- seq(-1,1,.01)
plot(0,0, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1))
curve(sqrt(1-x^2), add=TRUE)
curve(-sqrt(1-x^2), add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but I am wondering if there exist a simpler way to graph it? (because for this one I have to figure out y=+-sqrt(1-x^2) myself)